# What function actually renders the wp_admin_bar ? How can I call it?

Tags: functions, themes, admin-bar

What function actually renders the wp_admin_bar? And how can I call it? I want to print out just the nodes / DOM for the actual menu. It would end up rendering something like this:

```
<div id="wpadminbar">
    <div class="quicklinks">
        <ul>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: I guess you're trying to modify the admin bar. These posts might help you... http://sumtips.com/2011/03/customize-wordpress-admin-bar.html , http://www.doitwithwp.com/customize-wordpress-admin-bar/ , http://digwp.com/2011/04/admin-bar-tricks/ .

Comment: I'm not trying to modify it. I'm actually just trying to render it separately from the footer.

Comment: Ohh... Sorry, wrong assumption! Btw, one of these posts has that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress admin bar is rendered by [`render()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L90) method in `WP_Admin_Bar` class, also you may need to check [`wp_admin_bar_render()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L41), it add few hooks before and after rendering and also calls this method